# Python Random Lunch Generator print restaurant type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am messing around in Demisto(automation/orchestration platform) and have created a playbook that uses a python automation that randomly selects lunch for the day.  This script randomly chooses a food type from the `lunch_list`, then from that list randomly selects a restaurant from that list.

```
import random

pizza_list=['Chuck E. Cheese','Target Pizza Hut',"Antonio's Pizza",'Romeos Pizza','Little Caesars',"Papa John's",'Dominos',"Pavona's Pizza Joint","Rocco's Pizza Shop","Teresa's Pizza","Mr. G's"]
sanwich_list=['Subway','Jersey Mikes','Penn Station','Firehouse Subs','The Sub Station','Magic Subs & Gyros',"Mr. Zub's Deli", 'Corral Sanwich Shop','Hanini Subs',"Jimmy John's"]
mexican_list=['Taco Bell','Funky Truckeria','Chipotle',"Tito's Mexican Grill",'Tres Potrillos','El Rancho',"Moe's Southwest Grill",'BOMBA Tacos','Qdoba','Casa Del Rio']
burger_list=['Wayback','The Rail','Five Guys',"Louie's Bar & Grille","Bob's Hamburg",'Swensons',"Rally's",'Skyway',"Hodge's Cafe","Wendy's",'Burger King',"McDonald's"]
healthy_list=['First Watch',"Ms. Julie's Kitchen",'Continental Cuisine',"Niko's Sandwich Board",'Poke Fresh','Zoup!',"Aladdin's Eatery","Beau's Grille",'Valley Cafe','CoreLife Eatery']
sit_down_list=["Friday's",'Red Lobster','Olive Garden',"Applebee's","P.F. Chang's","Rockne's Restaurant",'Akron Family Restaurant','BRAVO','Cracker Barrel','Wally Waffle','Kingfish',"Ken Stewart's Grille",'Long Horn','Lockkeepers','Bonefish Grille']
asian_list=['China King','Imperial Wok','China Star','Platinum Dragon','Sushi Asia Gormet','China Express','New Ming Restaurant','House of Hunan','Sushi Katsu','Sakura','T J Sushi','Big Eye Japanese Cuisine & Sushi Bar','Hong Kong Buffet','Taste of Bankok','Hyde Out']

lunch_list=[pizza_list,sanwich_list,mexican_list,burger_list,healthy_list,sit_down_list,asian_list]
rest_list=random.choice(lunch_list)
lunchview_list=random.choice(rest_list)

print (lunchview_list)
Jimmy John's
```

I have no problem getting the restraunt selected but I would like to also print the item in lunch list example: `sanwich_list`

How would I do that?

Comment: So basically you want to print the name of the variable? A minimal example would have been appreciated

Comment: Done @RiccardoBucco

Comment: If Riccardo is right and you want to also print the name of the list that the restaurant came from, I see at least one problem with that. That is, when you pull the list with `random.choice`, you are saving a reference of the list to your `rest_list` variable. Many variables can reference the same object and there's no guarantee you can extract the "correct" name from the `globals()` dictionary. Instead, you might want to organize your restaurants into a dictionary. IE `rest_dict = {"pizza_list": ["Chuck E. Cheese", …], "sanwich_list": ["Subway", …], …}`.

Comment: That was the problem I was running into, thank you for the guidance @SyntaxVoidsupportsMonica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest putting your various lists into a dictionary:

```
food_lists = {
    "pizza_list": ['Chuck E. Cheese','Target Pizza Hut',"Antonio's Pizza",'Romeos Pizza','Little Caesars',"Papa John's",'Dominos',"Pavona's Pizza Joint","Rocco's Pizza Shop","Teresa's Pizza","Mr. G's"],
    "sanwich_list": ['Subway','Jersey Mikes','Penn Station','Firehouse Subs','The Sub Station','Magic Subs & Gyros',"Mr. Zub's Deli", 'Corral Sanwich Shop','Hanini Subs',"Jimmy John's"],
    "mexican_list": ['Taco Bell','Funky Truckeria','Chipotle',"Tito's Mexican Grill",'Tres Potrillos','El Rancho',"Moe's Southwest Grill",'BOMBA Tacos','Qdoba','Casa Del Rio'],
    "burger_list": ['Wayback','The Rail','Five Guys',"Louie's Bar & Grille","Bob's Hamburg",'Swensons',"Rally's",'Skyway',"Hodge's Cafe","Wendy's",'Burger King',"McDonald's"],
    "healthy_list": ['First Watch',"Ms. Julie's Kitchen",'Continental Cuisine',"Niko's Sandwich Board",'Poke Fresh','Zoup!',"Aladdin's Eatery","Beau's Grille",'Valley Cafe','CoreLife Eatery'],
    "sit_down_list": ["Friday's",'Red Lobster','Olive Garden',"Applebee's","P.F. Chang's","Rockne's Restaurant",'Akron Family Restaurant','BRAVO','Cracker Barrel','Wally Waffle','Kingfish',"Ken Stewart's Grille",'Long Horn','Lockkeepers','Bonefish Grille'],
    "asian_list": ['China King','Imperial Wok','China Star','Platinum Dragon','Sushi Asia Gormet','China Express','New Ming Restaurant','House of Hunan','Sushi Katsu','Sakura','T J Sushi','Big Eye Japanese Cuisine & Sushi Bar','Hong Kong Buffet','Taste of Bankok','Hyde Out']}
```

Then you can make a random choice from the keys.

```
category = random.choice(list(food_lists.keys()))
rest_list=random.choice(food_lists[category])
print(category)
print(rest_list)
```